# What difference between "pip install" and "setup.py install" for static files

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a problem with pip && setuptools. I have a simple project here: https://github.com/rmuslimov/rapidlog

If I make these commands:

```
mkvirtualenv rtests
pip install git+file:///%path_to_this_project%
rapidagent # This my app in this project
```

It works properly and creates templates and static files.

If I do:

```
mkvirtualenv rtests
cd %path_to_this_project%
python setup.py install
rapidagent
```

It cannot install my templates and static files data. So I can't start my application.

Here is the end of my setup.py file:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'rapidagent = rapidlog.web.webagent:main'
        ],
    },
include_package_data=True,
data_files=[('rapidlog/web/templates', ['rapidlog/web/templates/index.html']),
            ('rapidlog/web/static/css', glob('rapidlog/web/static/css/*')),
            ('rapidlog/web/static/images', glob('rapidlog/web/static/images/*')),
            ('rapidlog/web/static/js', glob('rapidlog/web/static/js/*')),
            ],
install_requires=[
    'pika>=0.9.5',
    'tornado>=2.3',
    'wsgiref>=0.1.2',
],
classifiers=[
    'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
    'Programming Language :: Python'
    ]
```

What special command does pip call ? What is the better way to solve this?

Comment: I just did what you say you did and it all works here.

Check my output: https://gist.github.com/3185285

Comment: Can you check in browser http://localhost:6673 - after rapidagent started?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It says it can't find the templates and etc. I took a look at site-packages and your package was an `.egg` zip file. I think the first thing to try is to add `zip_safe=False` to your `setup` call. The next is creating a `MANIFEST.in` file instead of using `data_files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that your `os.path.join` calls are relative to the current directory your python is called. So, the first thing is:

```
web/webagent.py: Change os.path.join('templates') and os.path.join('static') to be absolute
```

I just sent your a [pull request with this change](https://github.com/rmuslimov/rapidlog/pull/1).

Update me with your next steps.